# Calling jsp page with url parameters from html

Tags: html, jquery, jsp

I have a form with 2 possible actions depending on check box value.. the form is in an html page, and one of the actions is reaching a jsp page with request parameters ... I tried to send an ajax call, like this:

```
  if (radiobtn is checked) {window.location.href = $('form').attr(
                                                            'action');}
else {$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           data: {
                  "param1": "stringVal1",
                  "param2": "stringVal2"
                 },
           url: 'page.jsp'}); }
```

the form action is another html page.
the jsp page I am trying to reach has the following code:

```
<%request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
String param1= request.getParameter("param1");
String param2= request.getParameter("param1");

if ((param1== null || param1== "") || (param2== null||param2.equals(""))){
        String qString = request.getQueryString().replaceAll("%26", "&");
        response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI()+"?"+qString);
    }
    %>
```

but this did not work... could someone help with this?

Comment: what doesn't work ? please elaborate

Comment: I am getting : RR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: and in Network tab in dev tools i am getting: Failed to load response data

Comment: ps: the same jsp page is beeing raeched from a third jsp page as a response to form action ... tried to remove that action but unfortunately yhis did not help

Comment: Currently your ajax looks to me.. not sure where might be problem without seeing more code . Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: I updated with more code ... hope it is clearer now :)

Comment: Your jsp code has `response.sendRedirect..` as you are using ajax here you cannot redirect from your jsp page and if you just need to check for null why not do that in jquery code ? and do redirection from there ? No need to use ajax.

Comment: The jsp code i am trying to reach is old code .. the html page is the new code i wrote... when i tried to reach the jsp by window.location.href =‘page.jsp’ i got java null pointer exception and 500 from the server.. apparently i was trying to reach it the wrong way.. but couldn’t find an answer of how to reach the jsp page from my js code

Comment: Hi, you can simply attach parameter which you need to pass i.e : `window.location.href ="page.jsp?param1=somevalue&param2=somevalue";` so that parameter will get pass to your jsp page.

Comment: I was missing one parameter which is beeing set in another function ... I tried it like you said: window.location.href ="page.jsp?param1=somevalue&param2=somevalue"; It works perfectly fine.. thanks a lot for you time. :)